# how to retrieve a complete list of users from firebase database?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am using the ***ionic framework***.I want to display all the users stored in my firebase database in the form of a list on a page. The way i am storing these users is by their uid like this :

`user
   |_uid1
   |   |_email:value
   |   |_tag:value
   |_uid2
   |   |_email:value
   |   |_tag:value
   |_...`

The problem i'm facing is that i don't know how to retrieve all the users and how to go through them one by one, displaying everybody's ***email ids***. How do i do it in ***typescript*** or ***javascript***? Please Help !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a community where we can help you with code, but the way your question reads it seems like you're asking to do the code for you.  Please read this guide on how to ask a good question and edit your post accordingly.  Thanks!  https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 1):

HERE is code snippet which i used to get all the users (user class can have any structure) from fire base.

```
 DatabaseReference  mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
 DatabaseReference  df = mDatabase.child("user");



    df.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            AllUserlist.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User user = new User();
                HashMap<String,Object> map= (HashMap<String, Object>)d.getValue();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(map);
                user = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, User.class);
                AllUserlist.add(user);

                }

                 }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

AllUserlist will have all the users data including the email which you need. Hope it helps !!

Comment: Is this javascript?

Comment: Thanks @RohitPadma but i forgot to mention in the question earlier that i need it in javascript. Do you know how to do that ?