# Get Image Links stored on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an mobile app with Android Studio and Firebase.

The structure of Database on Firebase like this:

```
"usuario_1":{   
    "id":"Gasdj21jk1231Hsd13",
    "datosusuario":{    
        "nombre":"JoseCarlos Diaz",
        "email":"jdiaz@gmail.com"
        "imagenprofile":"direccion de la imagen de perfil"
    }
        "esCliente" : true,
        "intereses":[   "deporte",
                        "musica",
                        "comida"
        ],
    "imagenes":[
        "hijoimagen_0123" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0124" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0125" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        }
    ]   
},
"usuario_2":{   
    "id":"Gasdj21jk1231Hsd13",
    "datosusuario":{    
        "nombre":"JoseCarlos Diaz",
        "email":"jdiaz@gmail.com"
        "imagenprofile":"direccion de la imagen de perfil"
    }
        "esCliente" : true,
        "intereses":[   "deporte",
                        "musica",
                        "comida"
        ],
    "imagenes":[
        "hijoimagen_0123" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0124" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        },
        "hijoimagen_0125" : {
            "idimagen":"Aqui vendra el id de la imagen",
            "urlimagen":"Aqui vendra la url de la imagen",      
            "categoria":"Categoria de la imagen",
            "Descripcion":"Descripcion de la imagen"
        }
    ]   
},
.
.
.
.
.
```

The aim is get all image links that are in the Database structure. I have to visiti every child of user and get the image links for finally obtain an array with all the imagen links.

Can someone help me with a query with Firebase on Android?

Comment: nothing :(

i'm starting with firebase and nosql databases

Comment: @JoseKaJCDiaz Hope this helps you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788090/how-to-retrieve-a-complete-list-of-users-from-firebase-database/44788295#44788295 Note : code is in Java.

Comment: @JoseKaJCDiaz you wish to display a list of pictures per user? or a list of users showing all picture for each user?

Comment: @JPVentura i wish get only the image links from all users, a  general list that only contains images links, i dont need know the user, only the image link and id imagen.

Comment: @JoseKaJCDiaz You can flatten your data, moving `imagenes` outside the user and inserting `user_id` as a picture attribute. See  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Answer (score 0):

According to [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database), you can populate a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) using a custom [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java).

If your list shows all pictures for a given user, you could simply use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to display a picture when you call `populateViewHolder`:

```
 Glide.with(context)
    .load(item.urlimagen)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(urlImageView);
```